Compute the Beta function with negative arguments
The beta function (not the beta distribution) beta(a,b) can be computed when a or b or both are negative. However, in the implementation of R, only non-negative arguments are allowed.
Is there a way around this?
A common definition of beta(a,b) is gamma(a)*gamma(b)/gamma(a+b); hence, we could use lgamma() to avoid overflow:
exp(lgamma(a)+lgamma(b)-lgamma(a+b))

but for some a or some b, say, when a <- -2.5; b <- 3, the solution to lgamma(a) should be a complex number yet R only returns the real part...

This question is likely to be closed unless, at the very least, you list every R package on CRAN (and bioconductor) which provides some sort of beta function and show that none of them support your need.

@CarlWitthoft : I am asked to know all the functions from unspecified sources?  How will I know that I have exhausted all the possible libraries? This is an impossible approach.

What's the basis of your claim that lgamma(a) should be a complex number for a <- -2.5?

@user2554330, gsl::lngamma_complex(-2.5) returns -0.05624372-3.141593i

if I thought about it some more I would presumably understand why the imaginary part of lngamma(-2.5) is -pi; it also worries me a bit that gsl::lngamma() happily returns results for negative integral values of x, where there is a pole ...

gamma(-2.5) is negative, but lgamma(-2.5) is documented to be the log of the absolute value of gamma(-2.5).

pracma::gammaz or gsl::lngamma_complex seem to work (and agree with Wolfram Alpha).
## convert values to complex (not sure if this is necessary)
a <- -2.5+0i; b <- 3+0i
library(pracma)
Re(gammaz(a)*gammaz(b)/(gammaz(a+b)))   ## -1.0667

Better (since as you point out it avoids overflow problems when a and b are large):
library(gsl)
exp((lngamma_complex(a)+lngamma_complex(b))-lngamma_complex(a+b))
## [1] -1.066667-1.30629e-16i

It's not obvious to me when the Beta function is real-valued; if you were confident that the result will be real, you can use Re() to drop the imaginary part of the result. Otherwise this answer might come in handy for dropping floating-point fuzz in the imaginary part ...

Works like a charm. Thank you.
